# Return data from php file to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am attempting to pass data between a php file back to a HTML file. I read on stack overflow that I should use AJAX or JQuery but i don't understand how to implement it (I am very new to the subject of web development so I apologize if this question is obvious). Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
body {background-color: powderblue;}

#head_canvas {
    width: 50;
    height: 20;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>

<div style="margin:0 auto" align=center>

    <canvas id="head_canvas" width="1400" height="90">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <form action="form_submit.php" method="post">
        <strong>Search: </strong><input type="text" name="search">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>


</div>


<body>



<script>
// Create the initial Header Box 
var c = document.getElementById("head_canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,95);
my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"DarkOrchid");
my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"white");

ctx.font="30px Verdana";
ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1400,90);

ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
ctx.fillText("Product Search", 700, 50);
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Get Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, 'username', 'password');
            if (!$conn) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else {
                echo "Successfully Connected To Database<br>";
            }

            /*
            INSERT INTO Members (MemberID, Pass, UserName) VALUES (1,'MyPas55w0rd','Johnny Bravo');
            */

            mysql_select_db("mydb",$conn);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM Members;";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                #echo $rows['MemberID'] . " , " . $rows['Pass'] . " , " . $rows['UserName'] . "<br>";
                echo array_values($rows)[1] . "<br>";
            }

            mysql_close();

        header('Location: index.html');
        exit;
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Suggest you study some ajax tutorials to get a better understanding of what it is and how it works....and importantly, how to debug it. This isn't a tutorial or code writing service

Comment: Doing a redirect after an `echo` doesn't make sense either

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are aware of this site or not but I'll give it to you anyway.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp provides lots of examples.

However, maybe you just need to copy all the information collected in your PHP code to a file that you can than read into your HTML code.  Something like:

```
<?php
echo copy("source.txt","target.txt");
?>
```

I hope one of the solutions I provided help you.

The UnderDog